# javascript scheme in url

Tags: javascript

please refer the code,

```
javascript:x=123;void();
```

so when u hit enter in the url ,browser wont replace the content of the page which is an expected result.Anyway since js executes the statement line by line ,when first statement gets executed the browser should immediately replace the content and than proceed to next isn't it?Can anyone explain how js executes the statement in the url and how placing void keyword at the end works.I only need help on these problem.Will var x be replaced with undefined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because, when used inline, the browser will replace the page contents with the return value of the last JavaScript statement **unless it's `undefined`**.

The value of the `void` operator happens to be `undefined`, which is why there's no content replacement. In fact, you could write your code like this too:

```
javascript:void(x=123);
```

See also: [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

Comment: plz can i have any reference on what u said .

Comment: but u just said when used inline the browser will replace the page contents with the value of the last.so when javascript:void x=123 ; browser will replace the content with 123

Comment: @Maizere `void(x=123)` is `undefined`.

Comment: i know that ,the only problem is with my statements.So where can i have a reference to this"browser replace the page contents with the last value  when used inline"

Comment: @Maizere It's in the reference to `void` that's in my answer.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-hoehrmann-javascript-scheme-01   """As an example,
   consider a HTML document containing a hyperlink like: `<a href='javascript:doSomething()'>...</a>` In typical implementations, when the user activates the hyperlink, the web browser will pass control to the doSomething() function, and **render its result, if any, in place of the current document**."""  (emphasis mine) But most details about this "in-context evaluation" were left as "out of scope".